# Python: Multiple IP addresses in one Excel sheet cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am writing a script that deals with finding IP addresses and matching them based on where those IPs are located, as well as several other criteria.

I've been using openpyxl to read in data from the spreadsheets, however the issue I'm having is that some cells have multiple IP addresses, so when I attempt to read from these cells I end up with all the IPs together in one long string. I was wondering if there's a suitable way to separate these IP's into individual ones in a list that can be iterated over.

My attempt at storing them in a list ended up with each individual character being stored as an element within this list.

```
...

ip_data = []
for row in sheet.cell(i, col_source_IP).value:
    ip_data.append(row)

...
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: An example of the problematic case?

Comment: when you read a cell with multiple IP addresses, check if they are in different lines, if so when you read them the string would contain '\n' so you could split the read cell with `\n`, store in a list and iterate them. this works even if there is only a single IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip_data = []
for row in sheet.cell(i, col_source_IP).value:
    temp_list = row.split('\n') # if IPs are seperated by \n
    for ip in temp_list:
      ip_data.append(ip)
```

Comment: Perfect, I was attempting to modify the data within the list rather than before the list! guess I have tunnel vision! Thanks very much for the fix! I'll accept it when it allows me to